# Symfony 2 : Best practice

Tags: symfony

I have two questions and I hope somebody can answer them clearly.

Q1 : Is it recommended to use the same symfony envelop for different projects (each project would be a bundle). In any case, can you explain why it has to be done or not.

Q2 : is it recommended (and possible) to move the vendor folder outside the project envelop to be used by different projects. So just one vendor for different projects.

Thank you for answering those questions.

Comment: What do you mean with "symfony envelop"?

Comment: I means the folder containing the app, bin, scr, vendor, web

Comment: No that doesn't sound like a good idea. Each project will likely have different dependencies which would make it horrible to, for example, share the `vendor` directory.

Comment: Let's say all the project have normally the same vendor... I would like answers with arguments please. I quite think too it is not a good idea but I would like arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1:
clearly it seems to be a bad idea. I don't think that's possible, even if that is possible, that is a bad idea for many reasons :

- the entry point of "symfony envelop" (app.php) is for one project
- your project scpecific configration (app folder)
- the deployements, if you have to deploy projectA but you have some devs on projectB which can't be deployed ?
  Q2:
- same reasons.

Overall :

- Every project is different.
- I don't think your projects will evolve
  at the exactly same time that's why it's a bad idea

Comment: it might be possible by modifying the app/autoload.php file, but for the same reasons presented before, i don't think that's a good idea.